# how to use tailwinds @apply with @layer directive from a Svelte component

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css, svelte-3, sveltekit

I want to use apply to define some css setting on a component, and I also want to be able to overwrite it, like this:

```html
<!-- CustomButton.svelte -->
<script>
    let className = '';
    export { className as class };
    export let label = 'Click me!';
</script>

<button class="custom-button {className}">{label}</button>

<style lang="postcss">
.custom-button {
    @apply bg-blue-400 font-bold text-white rounded-lg p-4;
}
</style>
```

And I want to use it like this:

```html
<script>
    import CustomButton from './CustomButton.svelte';
</script>

<div class="w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
    <CustomButton class="bg-red-800" label="This is my button" />
</div>
```

That is, I want to be able to override my @applied settings

The problem is that the settings from thw @apply directives cannot be overriden by this line

`<button class="custom-button {className}">{label}</button>`

I understand that in order to do that I have to tell tailwind to generate the corresponding css in the components layer, that is, before the utilities.

If I enter the same css directive in my `app.post.css` file, before the `@tailwind utilities` line, or using the `@layer components` directives it works ok:

```
/* app.post.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* This works ok! */
@layer components {
  .custom-button {
    @apply bg-blue-400 font-bold text-white rounded-lg p-4;
  }
}
```

So, what I want is some way to tell tailwind to add the `.custom-button` setting I defined at my `CustomButton.svelte` component to the components layer, so that it could be overriden with inline clases.

If I try to do this in my `CustomButton.svelte` file

```
<style lang="postcss">
    @layer components {
        .custom-button {
            @apply bg-blue-400 font-bold text-white rounded-lg p-4;
        }
    }
</style>
```

I get the following error:

```
9:13:34 PM [vite] Internal server error: /home/sas/devel/apps/glas-it/apps/wingback/end-user-portal/src/routes/CustomButton.svelte?svelte&type=style&lang.css:1:1: `@layer components` is used but no matching `@tailwind components` directive is present.
  Plugin: vite:css
```

This issue is preventing me from using the `@apply` directive from any component.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to use @tailwind directives and functions on SvelteKit by importing it inside config :

```js
// svelte.config.js

+import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
+import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

 const config = {
...
+  preprocess: sequence([
+    sveltePreprocess({
+      postcss: {
+        plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer]
+      }
+    }),
+  ]),
...
}
```

NB: This was already set inside my postcss.config.cjs file but it did not work.

However, using the `@tailwind components` directive inside a `<style>` component tag :

- Throws a warning with `svelte-check` ("Unknown at rule @tailwind")
- Throws a warning with `vite-plugin-svelte` ("Unused CSS selector")

So, the easiest way seems to keep tailwind components inside your global app.css until better support.

Comment: where exactly is the preprocess, is it a key in the config object, or is it part of the plugins array

Comment: @Password-Classified it's a key in the config object, see https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#what-is-it

Comment: +1 & thanks. Just to say I had to tweak it for it to work.. `... preprocess: [ preprocess({ postcss: true, plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer] }), ], ...`

Answer (score 1):

[Tailwind document](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit) miss some config in `svelte.config.js`.
The config below work in new SvelteKit project.

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // here you enable postcss, and you can use @apply directive
    preprocess: preprocess({ postcss: true }),

    ...
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Isn't everything in svelte-preprocess already enabled by default?

Comment: No, you should enable postcss explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Tailwindcss documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#using-apply-with-per-component-css), you can't use @layer with @apply inside a framework's component, including Svelte (it actually mentions it). The solution is to create your own plugin to define *applyable* classes:

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addComponents, theme }) {
      addComponents({
        '.card': {
          backgroundColor: theme('colors.white');
          borderRadius: theme('borderRadius.lg');
          padding: theme('spacing.6');
          boxShadow: theme('boxShadow.xl');
        }
      })
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: The docs mentions that you can't use `@apply` inside your component's style only for the custom class defined in your global CSS. OP's not trying to use `@apply` with a custom class.